# Multiple file upload with Spring 3 and Hibernate 4

Tags: spring, hibernate, file-upload

I am new to Spring MVC and Hibernate and am learning along the way.

I encountered this problem when I was trying to upload images onto the site and store it in MySQL database.

I have a project model, which consists of a list of photo model. In each photo model, there is a field (CommonsMultipartFile) called photo that actually stores the photo.

ProjectModel.java

```
public class ProjectModel{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<PhotoModel> photos;
    //getters and setters
}
```

PhotoModel.java

```
public class PhotoModel extends AbstractModel implements Serializable{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    @Column(columnDefinition = "LONGBLOB")
    private CommonsMultipartFile photo;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private ProjectModel project;
    //getters and setters
}
```

addProject.jsp

```
<form:input type="file" path="photos[0].photo"/>
<form:input type="file" path="photos[1].photo"/>
```

ProjectController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value="/project/add", method = {RequestMethod.GET})
public String toAddProject (Model model){
    if (!model.containsAttribute(Constants.COMMAND)){
        ProjectModel project = new ProjectModel();
        project.setPhotos(new AutoPopulatingList<PhotoModel>(PhotoModel.class));
        model.addAttribute(Constants.COMMAND, project);
    }
    return "/user/addProject";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/project/add", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
public String addProject Model model, @ModelAttribute("command") @Valid ProjectModel command, BindingResult result){

    if(result.hasErrors()) {
            model.addAttribute(Constants.COMMAND, command);
            return toAddProject(model);
        }

     projectService.save(command);
     return "redirect:/success";
}
```

My problem is that I am able to upload images of certain types, such as jpg or jpeg, but not png. If I try to upload such file, the error is as follows.

```
    org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateSystemException: could not deserialize; nested exception is org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SessionFactoryUtils.convertHibernateAccessException(SessionFactoryUtils.java:206)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateTransactionManager.java:606)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:488)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy32.save(Unknown Source)
    at cn.javass.demo.web.controller.ProjectController.addProject(ProjectController.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:213)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:126)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:96)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:617)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:80)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:789)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:77)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at cn.javass.common.web.filter.BackURLFilter.doFilter(BackURLFilter.java:37)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:307)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
Caused by: org.hibernate.type.SerializationException: could not deserialize
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:250)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.deserialize(SerializationHelper.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.clone(SerializationHelper.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor$SerializableMutabilityPlan.deepCopyNotNull(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:55)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.SerializableTypeDescriptor$SerializableMutabilityPlan.deepCopyNotNull(SerializableTypeDescriptor.java:42)
    at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.MutableMutabilityPlan.deepCopy(MutableMutabilityPlan.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.deepCopy(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:340)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.deepCopy(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeHelper.deepCopy(TypeHelper.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityUpdateAction.execute(EntityUpdateAction.java:135)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:276)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1127)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:325)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doCommit(HibernateTransactionManager.java:480)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Paddy/Documents/apache-tomcat-7.0.25/work/Catalina/localhost/Spring3Hibernate4Chinese/upload_1bc5d431_136acd506da__8000_00000013.tmp (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.readObject(DiskFileItem.java:709)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:969)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1848)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:1946)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1870)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1752)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.SerializationHelper.doDeserialize(SerializationHelper.java:244)
    ... 72 more
```

It seems that a temporary file cannot be found. I am not sure what is really happening behind the scenes by Spring or Hibernate.

Really hope someone could shed some lights on this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: could anyone help? Really appreciate it.

Comment: Do you have your form enctype set to "mulitpart/form-data" and see the [documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-multipart) if you are missing anything. Another useful [link](http://www.raistudies.com/spring/spring-mvc/file-upload-spring-mvc-annotation/)

Comment: @Ravi Thanks for your reply. I did set the form enctype set to "multipart/form-data". I looked into the example you provided before I attempted this actually. The scenario is different though. In the example, the image is not persisted into the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting with this issue for a while, it seems that it does not depend on the type of file I submit but rather the size of the file. If it exceeds a threshold, the problem described occurs.

Since I am not able to tackle this issue, I tried to convert field type from `CommonsMultipartFile` to `byte[]` and add an initBinder method at my controller as suggested by this [link](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-failed-to-convert-property-value-in-file-upload-form/).

It works.